# Applescript to disable scheduled shutdown if #%n app is running?

Tags: applescript, osx-mountain-lion

Is there an Applescript somewhere that can tell the [Energy Saver shutdown scheduler](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10834) in OSX 10.8 "don't shut down the computer if #%n app is running?"  I use the Energy Saver scheduler to shut down my machine in the evenings and power back up in the mornings, but sometimes I need to let an app run overnight.

I know about [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/), but I want something automated, hence the script - I want the script to tell the Energy Scheduler, "Hey, #%n app is running, *don't* shut down tonight" without requiring me to do anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is not use the Energy Saver shutdown scheduler at all, and instead use the Calendar application to schedule when to run this little script to conditionally shutdown the system.

In this example, I have set this up for iTunes, but you can change this to any application you require.

Use the `Applescript Editor` to create and save a script like this:

```
set myapp to "iTunes"
if application myapp is not running then
    tell application "Finder" to shut down
end if
```

Open the `Calendar` application and set up a new event which occurs whenever you want the scheduled shutdown to occur e.g. every day at 9pm.  In the "New Event" box, you can change the "alert" field to "Open File", then change the file to be opened to the script that you just saved.

The script should run when you have scheduled it, and only shutdown the system if iTunes (or whichever application you want) is not running.

Note that `tell application "Finder" to shut down` will do a "careful" shutdown - i.e. if there are any other applications which don't want to be shutdown, then the shutdown will be cancelled.